# How to send message to the person who added the bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have an event and when someone invites the bot it's sending a thank you letter message but to the server owner. How to make it to send it to the person who added the bot, not the server owner?

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Здрастии! Аз съм <@789920350796251198> и много ти благодаря, че ме покани в **{guild.name}**! Използвай .help, за да видиш списък с командите ми! Целта ми е да мога да се използвам във всеки български сървър. През времето ще се усъвършенствам и ще имам модули за музика, билети, логове и много други <:bcbwelcome:789925513748676638>",color=0x33AB8B,)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"За въпроси - .support | Версия - 0.1")
    await guild.owner.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: That's unfornatelly not possible

Comment: I think it's possible because so many bots dm'ed me with messages like "Hey, thank you for inviting me in your server"

Comment: Probably cause you're the owner of the server, it's not possible with discord.py

Comment: Oh okay thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Audit Logs to do such, as new `bot_add` was added

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    entry = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.bot_add).flatten()
    entry = entry[0]
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"Здрастии! Аз съм <@789920350796251198> и много ти благодаря, че ме покани в **{guild.name}**! Използвай .help, за да видиш списък с командите ми! Целта ми е да мога да се използвам във всеки български сървър. През времето ще се усъвършенствам и ще имам модули за музика, билети, логове и много други <:bcbwelcome:789925513748676638>",color=0x33AB8B,)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"За въпроси - .support | Версия - 0.1")
    await entry.user.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much mate! :) Good luck and stay safe! :)